# Change font in HeatMap() of Matlab Bioinformatics Toolbox

Tags: matlab, bioinformatics, heatmap

I'm using the Bioinformatics Toolbox in Matlab 2016a. I created a matrix with row and column labels using `mat = DataMatrix()` and then I create a heatmap using `fig = HeatMap(mat)`. The row and column labels are added to the resulting figure automatically.

I want to change all fonts in the resulting figure to Arial. I also want to stop underscores being interpreted as subscripts. However, the command:

```
fig = HeatMap(mat,'Colormap','fontName','Arial','Interpreter','none')
```

results in errors:

```
Unknown parameter name: fontName.
Unknown parameter name: Interpreter.
```

and the command:

```
set(fig,'fontName','Arial','Interpreter','none')
```

results in:

```
The name 'fontName' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'HeatMap'.
The name 'Interpreter' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'HeatMap'.
```

How can I get the result I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the HeatMap view (what is shown when the HeatMap object is constructed) is not equivalent to a regular plot, and is fairly inflexible. Luckily, the HeatMap can be rendered as a plot instead, which allows for manipulation. The example is lifted from [This Mathworks site](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ug/representing-expression-data-values-in-datamatrix-objects.html).

```
load filteredyeastdata
yeastvalues = yeastvalues(1:5, 1:4);
genes = genes(1:5, :);
genes = strrep(genes, 'L', 'L_'); %// simulate underscores
times = times(1:4);
dat = DataMatrix(yeastvalues, genes, times);
heatmap = HeatMap(dat); %// no way to suppress?
```

[image]

It's possible to see the available properties of the `HeatMap` object using `properties(<object>)` or `set(<object>)` (to list current settings). From there, it's straightforward to see what properties are not available (no 'fontName' or 'Interpreter').

Mathworks gives us a `plot` method for HeatMaps, which gives us a wider range of options.

```
plt = plot(heatmap); %// render the heat map and give us a handle
```

There are an awful lot of properties associated with `plt`, but it looks like the one you want is 'TickLabelInterpreter' (see [Axes Properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html)).

`set` can take cell arrays or key-value pairs as inputs, which allow us to set multiple properties in one go.

```
set(plt, {'Fontname', 'TickLabelInterpreter'}, {'Comic Sans MS', 'none'});
%// or set(plt, 'Fontname', 'Comic Sans MS', 'TickLabelInterpreter', 'none');
```

[image]

Note that MATLAB *is* case-sensitive!